# What would you call this type of song?

Tags: word-request

I always liked a certain type of songs, and I can't find anything about the name for these kinds of songs; here's a ***[link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oxpSP7QEAWY)*** of the kind of song I mean.

I mean, there is country music, rock music, and barbershop quartets; what category does this this song belong in?

Thanks
(I'm not English, so if the question isn't clear feel free to ask for clarifications)

Comment: It's called "pop music."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with English, and worse, it requires the application of a subjective label.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. It is actually an interesring  question despite the fact that there may be disagreement about the musical genre OP is referring to.

Comment: In the future, if you have such questions, you can consider the site http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call that *a capella*, or "without instrumental accompaniment" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20cappella)), and specifically [**Pentatonix**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU_mcNMHvxil0QCxZZB8cjWEiCZEAJRvm)-style:

> tight vocal harmonies, extensive vocal riffing, deep and steady vocal
>   basslines, and a diverse range of vocal percussion and beatboxing.
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pentatonix&oldid=738188914))

I believe that, as is common with Pentatonix and this style, the linked example in the original post [gives the illusion of instruments through the use of layered vocals](https://www.quora.com/How-fake-are-Pentatonix). It is possible that it is in fact accompanied, and giving the illusion of Pentatonix-style a capella, but I'd call it Pentatonix-style in either case.

Note that Pentatonix didn't invent this; [Bobby McFerrin, for one, preceded them](http://dailybruin.com/2013/02/13/against-the-grain-bobby-mcferrin-pentatonix-redefined-use-of-vocals/). However, the smooth pop-style and particular sound of Pentatonix appear to be what the example is trying to approximate.

Answer (score 5):

The song is called [Can't Stop the Feeling!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can%27t_Stop_the_Feeling!) by Justin Timberlake. The link seems to be a cover. Broadly speaking, this genre is *pop*. However, the article says

> Musically, it is an uptempo disco-pop, soul-pop number with funk influences.

It's hard to say exactly what genre the these songs fit into, since they are a blend on genres. But the linked video does seem to have a barbershop music style at the beginning, possibly doo-wop as Mark points out. Towards the end it seems to be closer in genre to the original. These are the key words you want to search when looking for similar songs.

Answer (score 5):

The word you might be looking for is 'genre'. This is a word that describes what classification or subcategory of music a song belongs to.

Unfortunately, song genre boundaries tend to be a little fuzzy or unclear, since as music evolves over time many 'new' genres copy from older song genres.

In the case of the song you linked, I would classify it as being of the genre of 'Do-Wop', which usually has 'main' singer with several backup singers which act as most of the song's 'instrumentals'. Do-wop can also include normal (non-voice) instruments in the song as well, while the 'barbershop quartet' genre requires four singers with no other instruments in the song (only human voice is allowed, otherwise known as 'a cappella' music).

Note also that the word 'genre' is used to discuss other forms of media subcategories as well, so in movies you might talk about the 'cowboy movie genre' and in books you might talk about the 'horror book genre'.